# How to extract chemical entities with ChemDataExtractor?

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to process a text for extracting chemical entities through ChemDataExtractor (Python). A possible example is

```
from chemdataextractor import Document
doc = Document('UV-vis spectrum of 5,10,15,20-Tetra(4-carboxyphenyl)porphyrin in Tetrahydrofuran (THF).')
```

and typing `doc.cems` the result is the following list

```
[Span('THF', 82, 85),
 Span('5,10,15,20-Tetra(4-carboxyphenyl)porphyrin', 19, 61),
 Span('Tetrahydrofuran', 65, 80)]
```

I would like to extract only `'THF'`, `'5,10,15,20-Tetra(4-carboxyphenyl)porphyrin'`, `'Tetrahydrofuran'`, without having the "span elements". How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
doc.cems[0].text

doc.cems[1].text

doc.cems[2].text
```